# Combine multiple cameras into one stream

Tags: image, image-processing

I'm new to the field and I've just started to work for a project related to a miniature version of cooperative and automated driving and have to come up with a solution to a problem

> There is a miniature racing track for [mini-GCDC](http://www.gcdc.net/en/) tournament; cars have to be be monitored from top-down cameras. Instead of using a single, wide-angle camera the video stream has to be combined from multiple, smaller cameras.

I've read a somewhat similar topic [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26193/is-it-possible-to-combine-multiple-cameras-for-improved-detail), however, I am not sure if it is what I am looking for. Are there any projects/concepts available regarding the topic?

Comment: so the cameras are fixed and scanning in almost the same (coplanar) projection planes? in such case after propper calibration the combining is easy ... just projection to common plane where your master screen is ... Sadly You are asking for off site stuff which is off topic so +Close. Anyway bigger problem would be the image acquisition in RT itself which mostly depends on The HW involved we know nothing of

Comment: @Spektre yes, the cameras are fixed and scattered across the room.

Comment: @Spektre it is crucial to have the whole image. Moreover, the cameras have to be synchronized and, most probably, calibrated on sw level. Related video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMj4I9c4yEY

Comment: Is there any question?